# A navigation bar with two separate color states

Tags: javascript, html, css, navigation

I'm trying to make a navigation bar with one category being a different color (blue) than the others (green). When you hover off of this blue HOME category, it needs to turn green. The category that is hovered over should turn blue, then return to green when not hovered over. Here are some pictures for reference:

Default/Home state: User starts on the Home page. The Home category is blue to show the user where they are.

[image]

Employer state: User has navigated to the Employer Page. The Home category is now green.

[image]

I am working in SFMC, so I have to include all HTML, CSS, and Javascript in one collection. Here is the code that I have:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
```

```css
.body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #47a23f;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.topnav a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #005da6;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #005da6;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #47a23f;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #003150;
  color: #fff;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Workforce 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a target="blank" href="https://myactivehealth.com/Portal/PreRegistrations/Index">Request to enroll</a>
      <a target="blank" href="https://www.myactivehealth.com/Portal/Registration/RegistrationStep1?IsoAuthDPRequest=False">Create an account</a>
      <a target="blank" href="https://www.myactivehealth.com/Portal/PortalLogin.aspx?SupplierURL=15571">Log in</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="#contact">Employer</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Injured Workers 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a target="blank" href="https://www.myactivehealth.com/Portal/Registration/RegistrationStep1?IsoAuthDPRequest=False">Create an account</a>
      <a target="blank" href="https://www.myactivehealth.com/Portal/PortalLogin.aspx?SupplierURL=15571">Log in</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: And what is the question? It seems to do what you want or do you want it to be sticky after clicking?

Comment: The hovering making color change works OK as @mplungjan has pointed out. I suspect you what your problem is is how to make the relevant tab become blue when another page is actually entered. Is that so?

Comment: @mplungjan What's the Question

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is to make `active` elements turn back to their normal color when hovering over other elements all you have to do is to add this at the bottom of your CSS:

```css
.topnav > .active {
  background-color: #005da6;
}

.topnav:hover > .active {
  background-color: inherit;
}

.topnav > .active:hover {
  background-color: #005da6;
}

.dropdown-content > .active {
  background-color: #003150;
}

.dropdown-content:hover > .active {
  background-color: inherit;
}

.dropdown-content > .active:hover {
  background-color: #003150;
}
```

If you just want some ideas for `active` elements handling, take a look to the following simplified snippet:

(NOTE: Below navigation bar works with pure HTML and CSS (No JS). JS is being used only to change the active elements automatically when the browser URL changes.)

```js
// * THIS IS ONLY A DEMONSTRATIVE EXAMPLE *

const links = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.topnav a'));

const addActive = (elem) => {
  let current = elem;
  
  while (current && !current.classList.contains('topnav')) {
    if (current.classList.contains('dropdown')) {
      current.classList.add('active');
      break;
    }
    current = current.parentElement;
  }
  
  elem.classList.add('active');
};

const handler = (e) => {
  const previousA = document.querySelector('.topnav .active');
  const previousB = document.querySelector('.dropdown-content .active');
  
  if (previousA) {
    previousA.classList.remove('active');
  }
  
  if (previousB) {
    previousB.classList.remove('active');
  }
  
  const next = links.find((link) => location.href === link.href) || links[0];
  
  if (next) {
    addActive(next);
  }
};

window.addEventListener('popstate', handler);
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', handler);
```

```css
.body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #47a23f;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.topnav a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #005da6;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #47a23f;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #003150;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.topnav > .active {
  background-color: #005da6;
}

.topnav:hover > .active {
  background-color: inherit;
}

.topnav > .active:hover {
  background-color: #005da6;
}

.dropdown-content > .active {
  background-color: #003150;
}

.dropdown-content:hover > .active {
  background-color: inherit;
}

.dropdown-content > .active:hover {
  background-color: #003150;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="topnav">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Workforce 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#workforce-a">Request to enroll</a>
      <a href="#workforce-b">Create an account</a>
      <a href="#workforce-c">Log in</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <a href="#employer">Employer</a>
  
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Injured Workers 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#injured-workers-a">Create an account</a>
      <a href="#injured-workers-b">Log in</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```